# libgdx ground doesnt work

Tags: java, libgdx, kotlin

i'm following along this tutorial https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d and i'm currently stuck at static objects. Here is my game class:

```
package com.mygdx.physics

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape



class Physics : ApplicationAdapter() {
    internal var batch: SpriteBatch? = null
    internal var world: World = World(Vector2(0.toFloat(), -10.toFloat()), true)
    internal var camera: OrthographicCamera = OrthographicCamera()
    internal var debugRenderer: Box2DDebugRenderer? = null
    internal var bodyDef: BodyDef = BodyDef()
    internal var body: Body? = null

    private var groundBodyDef: BodyDef = BodyDef()
    private var groundBox: PolygonShape = PolygonShape()
    private var groundBody: Body? = null

    override fun create() {
        createBody()
        createBall()
        createGround()

        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800f, 480f)
        debugRenderer = Box2DDebugRenderer()
    }

    override fun render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        camera.update()
        debugRenderer?.render(world, camera.combined);
        world.step(1/45f, 6, 2);
    }

    override fun dispose() {
    }

    private fun createBody() {
      bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody
      bodyDef.position.set(100.toFloat(), 300.toFloat())
      body = world.createBody(bodyDef)
    }

    private fun createBall() {
      BallHandler(body).createBall()
    }

    private fun createGround() {
      groundBodyDef = BodyDef()
      groundBodyDef.position.set(Vector2(0f, 10f))

      groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef)

      groundBox = PolygonShape()
      groundBox.setAsBox(camera.viewportWidth, 10.0f)
      groundBody?.createFixture(groundBox, 0.0f)
      groundBox.dispose()
    }
}
```

As you can see i implemented it in almost identical way. they ball part works like a charm, the rest is compiling but i cannot see the created ground, nor its effect. why is that or how can I effectively debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your `create` method:

```
override fun create() {
    createBody()
    createBall()
    createGround()

    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800f, 480f)
    debugRenderer = Box2DDebugRenderer()
}
```

You're setting the camera dimensions after you call `createGround`, yet `createGround` already makes use of `camera.viewportWidth`. Therefore, the ground body has a width of zero.

Move the call to `setToOrtho` to the start of the method.

Additionally, here's a Kotlin tip: instead of having many nullable variables, use [lateinit properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) instead to avoid all of the unnecessary null checks.

You could also make some of your fields local variables instead, such as `groundBodyDef`.